# python convert long function into class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im looking to convert this python script into a class which accepts an object. The goal is to better structure the program as there will be additional functions/classes. Any help in the right direction would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
import serial
import time
vin_number = ''

def connect():
    ser=serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0', 115200)
    ser.write(b'ATL1\r\n')
    ser.write(b'ATH1\r\n')
    ser.write(b'ATS1\r\n')
    ser.write(b'ATSP0\r\n')
    ser.write(b'0902\r\n')
    time.sleep(5)
    resp  = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
    return resp

def parse_vin(rcv):
    result = rcv.split(' ')
    row1 = " ".join(result[6:9])
    row2 = " ".join(result[11:18])
    row3 = " ".join(result[20:27])
    vin_hex = row1 + row2 + row3
    return vin_hex

def decode_vin(vin_hex):
    vin = str(bytearray.fromhex(vin_hex).decode())
    return vin

try:
    rcv = "7E8 10 14 49 02 01 4C 46 56 7E8 21 33 42 32 38 52 38 41 7E8 22 33 30 32 35 33 31 30"
    #rcv = connect()
    vin_hex = parse_vin(rcv)
    vin_number = decode_vin(vin_hex)
    print(vin_number)

except Exception as e:
print(e)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a class that accepts an object"? Can you show us what you want the interface of the class to be like? How will you construct instances? What methods will you call on them or what attributes will you access or set?

Comment: Meanwhile, the vast majority of your code here is completely unnecessary. Just remove all those `posN = result[N]` lines entirely, and use `result` as a list. It's not like the name `pos10` is any more meaningful than `result[10]`. And, meanwhile, if you want to join up elements 6-26, leaving them in a list means you can just write `vin_hex = " ".join(result[6:27])`. (You don't even need the spaces for `fromhex`… but they might be useful for debugging, so that's fine.)

Comment: Finally, you're asking how to convert a function to a class, but you don't even have any functions yet. And some functions could definitely be useful here: a `def parse_vin(rcv):` that takes a `rcv` string and returns a `vin_number` string, a `def read_vin(ser):` that takes a `Serial` object and reads and parses a vin, and then your top-level code is just the `ser = …` and call to `read_vin(ser)` plus the `try`/`except`.

Comment: I think `loops` and `functions` will help you, you can go for `class` when you have implemented those two. Work from their will mostly be straightforward. **Hint**: `pos0` to `pos26` could be done with a `loop`

Comment: @abarnert thanks for the direction.
i broke the script out into 3 functions.

def connect():

def parse_vin(rcv):

def decode_vin(vin_hex):

with a try catch exception

updated the original code since it was too long for the comment